# Is Socket.flush() necessary after reading data?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, sockets

I am having problems with a project which makes intensive use of sockets with Smartfox Server. Sometimes, with Chrome, sockets data seems to contain previous data (message from SFS are in double).

Anyway my question is pretty simple ; anytime you read data from a socket, are you supposed to call the flush() method after ? I know it's highly recommended to do so when you are sending data.

```
....
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, handleSocketData);
....

private function handleSocketData(evt:Event):void
{
    var o:Object = socket.readObject();
    ....
    socket.flush(); // is that necessary???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** It is to [flush the output data.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html#flush%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

No, you should read the response data with something like -

```
  while ( socket.bytesAvailable ) {
        var data:String = socket.readUTF();
        Alert.show(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use Sockets in Flash with SFS server too. and we never flush the socket after reading, we only flush it (and must do) after writing to its byte buffer.